# Using PHP to output superscripted text

Tags: php, html

I am just learning PHP . i want to display string like " 32th meet " where "th" is in superscript format . i use `<sup> th </sup>` in php echo but it doesn't work . please give a solution to use superscript html tag in php.

Comment: I think I know why it doesn't work it's meant to be 32nd right?

Comment: This is far too vague, are you receiving any errors on the page? or is it just not superscripting the "th", if you view page source, do you see <sup> ??? More details please...

Comment: Before asking try to find an answer by reading php manual en html manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

32<sup>th</sup> meet

[W3Schools TryIt page for superscript/subscript tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_sup) & [also try the Tizag explanation page](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlsuperscript.php).

Comment: Care to describe what you're linking to?

Comment: Thanks for replay . i got working now and another one is how to display the same string in Cell for ex: $this->Cell(0,10,$t_digit."<sup>".$t_SuperScript."</sup>",0,0);

Answer (score 1):

so I would use something like this:

You say that your `echo` does not work?

```
<?php
echo '34<sup>th</sup>';
?>
```

would do the job.